# Flex function appear order (actionscript)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

This is my function

```
private function dateChangeHandler(event:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show("hihi");
            Alert.show('You have selected ' +   ((event.target.selectedDate) as Date).toDateString());
            if ((event.target.id == "returnDate") && (pickupDate.selectedDate > returnDate.selectedDate))
            {
                Alert.show("Pickup date must be scheduled before return date.");
            }
        }
```

I don't know why "hihi" is always appeared lastly. Thx for giving explanation.

Comment: Each new alert goes below the last displayed one, so it looks like the last alert is the one with "hihi" (it's first so will be on the "top").

Answer (score 3):

This is correct and expected behaviour. I don't see why you need more than one alert dialog?
It will only prompt by alert's queue order after it complete the execution.